# ViewModel is not binding from the POST form when passed into a method as a parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mode

I'm new to asp.net mvc, but I've thoroughly searched on this topic everywhere.

I've a ViewModel class named PictureViewModel which is the class an EditorTemplate view inherits from:
    <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

```
<div class="editor-label"><%: Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Name) %></div> 
<div class="editor-field"><%: Html.TextBox("form.Name") %></div> 

<div class="editor-label"><%: Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Description) %></div> 
<div class="editor-field"><%: Html.TextArea("form.Description") %></div> 

<% Html.RenderAction("SelectCategory", "Category"); %>

<div class="editor-label"><label for="thumbFile">Thumb</label></div> 
<div class="editor-field"><input id="thumbFile" name="thumbFile" type="file"/></div> 

<div class="editor-label"><label for="fullFile">Full</label></div> 
<div class="editor-field"><input id="fullFile" name="fullFile" type="file"/></div>
```

Also I have file fields and all that is posted to itself

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="/Views/Shared/Site_Table.Master"
 Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplicationVelarPolya.Areas.Admin.Models.PictureViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Create
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Create</h2>

    <%
  using (Html.BeginForm("create", "Pictures", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data"})) 
   {%> 

    <%: Html.EditorForModel() %>

    <input type="submit" name="Create" />

<% }%>

</asp:Content>
```

And here is the code devoted to handle the submit:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Prefix="form")] PictureViewModel pm)
    {
        try
        {
            var p = new PictureViewModel();
            UpdateModel(p, "",new[] {"Name", "Description"});
            ViewData["name"] = Request.Files[0].FileName;
            return View("New", p);
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Neither adding prefixes, nor using FormCollection with UpdateModel doesn't help.
I would greatly appreciate any help!
Andrew.

Oh, yes, viewdata is popuated with filename correctly!

This is not working, too
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection fc/*[Bind(Prefix="form")] PictureViewModel pm*/)
        {
            try
            {
                var p = new PictureViewModel();
                UpdateModel(p, "form",new[] {"Name", "Description"});
                ViewData["name"] = Request.Files[0].FileName;
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                return View("New", p);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

And this code

```
        foreach (var k in fc)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(k.ToString());
        }
```

is producing

```
form.Name
form.Description
CategoryID
Create
```

Comment: add your FormCollection and look at the keys you are receiving. in it.

Comment: I've tried this, 4 keys exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your editor template you should use strongly typed helpers (`TextBoxFor` and `TextAreaFor`) and you could get rid of magic strings and prefixes:

```
<div class="editor-label"><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name) %></div> 
<div class="editor-field"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name) %></div> 

<div class="editor-label"><%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description) %></div> 
<div class="editor-field"><%: Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description) %></div> 

<% Html.RenderAction("SelectCategory", "Category"); %>

<div class="editor-label"><label for="thumbFile">Thumb</label></div> 
<div class="editor-field"><input id="thumbFile" name="thumbFile" type="file"/></div> 

<div class="editor-label"><label for="fullFile">Full</label></div> 
<div class="editor-field"><input id="fullFile" name="fullFile" type="file"/></div>
```

To handle uploaded files you could add them either as view model properties or as action parameters:

```
public class PictureViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase ThumbFile { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase FullFile { get; set; }
}

...

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PictureViewModel pm)
{
    // Normally the pm variable should be fully 
    // initialized here from the POST request and you can use it directly
    // No need to call UpdateModel
    return View("New", pm);
}
```